# npm build omits some vuetify elements

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, npm-scripts

Was having some trouble with building a shared app/package in vueJS, the app is using vuetify, what is interesting is that the built code contains almost everything except for `v-tooltip` that is inside `v-menu`. The commands I tried were `vue-cli-service build` and then `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name em-common-vue ./src/main.js`. 
I should note that I have been using this app with no issues until now!
Any idea why my build version is missing code?

vue 2.6.10
vuetify 1.5.14